# Does registering a directory in ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 work recursively?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
--Geodata
---------Raster
---------------Topographie
---------------Aerial_Images
---------------DGM
---------Vector
---------------Environment
---------------Transport
...etc
```

Do I just have to register the directory "Geodata" or do I have to register all separate directories which contain the data I would like to publish?

Comment: My guess is yes, as when I register a file geodatabase, I register the folder the geodatabase is in, not the actual gdb itself. And a geodatabase is just a folder of files, right? Have you tried it yet? Try it and see.

Comment: @ChadCooper I'm not sure that logic follows. To anything that doesn't know what a file geodatabase is, yes, it's just a folder of files. For something that does, like Arc, it's a specific kind of object and treated as such. I've had clients who stored independent files within the FGDB folder. Arc can't see or browse to them. It would seem reasonable (and docs state) register a folder, all file geodatabases and shapefiles, etc. within are seen. But subfolders are another matter (which docs also state do get registered). Admittedly Arc can be bad about what it actually wants you to point at.

Comment: @ChadCooper: That is an interesting concept! - making directories inside the actual FGDB. Why did the client do this? - just to organize their files together, or were there other reasons?

Comment: I never said anything about making directories inside the file geodatabase. @ChrisW, my point was simply for OP to try it and see if what he was wanting to do would indeed work.

Comment: Robert - reasons vary. Most of the time it's because they don't know any better (students, novices to Arc) and just think it's a regular old folder. To be clear, it's not recommended. Dumping a file or two in there won't necessarily hurt anything, but it could be difficult to find/sort out later, and if while mucking around in there you *do* happen to alter something important, poof goes the entire geodatabase. @Chad I just wanted to comment for the benefit of others/newbies that may find this that there *is* a distinction. You're certainly right, it does seem an easy enough thing to test.

Answer (score 2):

According to [About registering your data with ArcGIS Server](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/overview-register-data-with-arcgis-server.htm),

> When you register a folder, its subfolders are also registered.

Paragraph just above the second Note box.